# How do i run Mac OS 9 applications on a Mac OS X version 10.6.7?

Tags: macos

I found a whole bunch of old games my dad and I used to play on his Mac os9 that we loved! I wanted to download them to my current mac and play them. How would i go about playing these games?

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be plenty of emulation tools from my initial googling.

[MacHints did a piece on it.](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060509180914879)

[This looks helpful as well.](http://uneasysilence.com/archive/2006/08/7352/)